# saving dataframe changes with wb.save()

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Blessings,

I am trying to convert my current dataframe into a worksheet so i'll be able to save properly.

For some reason while trying to save to xlsx after editing a df using `df.to_excel` it overwrites to the top left row instead of editing the cells I originally changed.

`ws.save()` does seem to work fine though.

What I am using to write :

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import argparse
import logging
import sys
import os


# Create logger
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
                    handlers=[
                        logging.FileHandler(filename="info.log"),
                        logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
                    ])
logger = logging.getLogger()


def inventory():
    """This will allow interaction within Inventory.xlsx."""
    today = date.today()
    computer_date = today.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
    file = "MMEX Inventory.xlsx"
    df = pd.ExcelFile(file).sheet_names

    # Filter sheets
    counter = 0
    sheets = []
    for sheet in df:
        if sheet == "EXTRA" or sheet == "Inventory Rules" or sheet == "Removed lines" or sheet == "EOL_Hynix_SODIMM" \
                or sheet == "EV" or sheet == "LPDDR4" or sheet == "LP4":
            pass
        else:
            counter += 1
            sheets.append(sheet)

    # Added arguments to take
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Will allow interaction within Inventory")
    parser.add_argument("num", help="What memory are you looking for? min of 2 letters are "
                                    "sufficient.")
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--subtract", type=int, metavar='', help="Will add to mmex and subtract from cabinet")
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--add", type=int, metavar='', help="Will add to cabinet and subtract from mmex")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Loop through sheets
    counter = 0
    for i in sheets:
        if counter == len(sheets) + 1:
            break
        else:
            # Read xlsx and current sheet
            df = pd.read_excel(f"{file}", f"{sheets[counter]}")

            # Compare and keep matching columns
            a = df.columns
            b = ['IDC S/N', 'ECC', 'Cabinet Qty', 'MMEX', 'VDR']
            keep_columns = [x for x in a if x in b]

            # Maximum width on output
            pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
            pd.set_option('display.width', None)
            pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

            # Search within IDC S/N for argument
            df = df.loc[df['IDC S/N'].str.lower().str.contains(args.num.lower(), na=False), keep_columns]
            df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

            # Enable user to edit 'Cabinet Qty' or 'MMEX'
            if args.add:
                if df.empty:
                    pass
                else:
                    # Check whether calculation approves
                    check = df.loc[df["IDC S/N"].str.lower().str.contains(args.num.lower(),
                                                                          na=False), 'MMEX']
                    for num in check:
                        if num - args.add < 0:
                            print(f"\n\n{df}")
                            logger.info(f"\n\n\nYou cannot do that.\n"
                                        f"While available quantity on MMEX is {num}\n"
                                        f"You are trying to subtract it by {args.add}\n")
                            exit()
                        else:
                            pass

                    # Log user and changes
                    logger.info(f"\n\nBeing edited by - {os.getlogin()}")
                    logger.info(f"The following changes are being made in sheet - {sheets[counter]}\n{df}")

                    # Make changes to 'Cabinet Qty/MMEX'
                    df.loc[df['IDC S/N'].str.lower().str.contains(args.num.lower(),
                                                                  na=False), 'Cabinet Qty'] += args.add
                    df.loc[df['IDC S/N'].str.lower().str.contains(args.num.lower(),
                                                                  na=False), 'MMEX'] -= args.add

                    # Save changes
                    with pd.ExcelWriter(file,
                                        engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
                        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"{sheets[counter]}")
                    logger.info(f"The following changes have been made \n{df}")

            elif args.subtract:
                if df.empty:
                    pass
                else:
                    # Check whether calculation approves
                    check = df.loc[df["IDC S/N"].str.lower().str.contains(args.num.lower(),
                                                                          na=False), 'Cabinet Qty']
                    for num in check:
                        if num - args.subtract < 0:
                            print(f"\n\n{df}")
                            logger.info(f"\n\n\nYou cannot do that.\n"
                                        f"While available quantity on 'Cabinet Qty' is {num}\n"
                                        f"You are trying to subtract it by {args.subtract}\n\n")
                            exit()
                        else:
                            pass
                    # Log user and changes
                    logger.info(f"\n\nBeing edited by - {os.getlogin()}")
                    logger.info(f"The following changes are being made in sheet - {sheets[counter]}\n{df}")

                    # Make Changes to 'Cabinet Qty/MMEX'
                    df.loc[df["IDC S/N"].str.lower().str.contains(args.num.lower(),
                                                                  na=False), 'Cabinet Qty'] -= args.subtract
                    df.loc[df['IDC S/N'].str.lower().str.contains(args.num.lower(),
                                                                  na=False), 'MMEX'] += args.subtract

                    # Save changes
                    with pd.ExcelWriter(file,
                                        engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
                        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"{sheets[counter]}")
                    logger.info(f"The following changes have been made \n{df}")
            else:
                # Convert from float to int
                try:
                    df['MMEX'] = df['MMEX'].astype(int)
                    df['VDR'] = df['VDR'].astype(int)
                except KeyError:
                    pass
                finally:
                    pass

                # Will prevent empty dataframes when looping from sheets
                if df.empty:
                    counter += 1
                else:
                    print(f"\n{sheets[counter]}\n" f"{df}\n")
                    counter += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    inventory()
```

Its output :

[image]

It basically overwrites to the top left instead of appending the current df.

While wb.save() does this instead:

[image]

## Edit :

To summarize it all very shortly, I need to convert this df command `df = df.loc[df['IDC S/N'].str.lower().str.contains(args.num.lower(), na=False), keep_columns]`

Look within 'IDC S/N' for anything that contains args.num.lower as input and filter using only certain columns (keep_columns)

This needs to be converted into a ws commands (openpyxl), if anyone knows how to do this ill be more than happy :)

Comment: Alternatively if anyone knows a way to make DF save to its correct location it would work aswell :)

Comment: Could you please share more details about the problem? What's the expected output and what output are you getting correctly? It's a little difficult to visualise the issue without any visual info.

Comment: @medium-dimensional Edited the post, hopefully its clearer now :)

Answer (score 0):

OpenPyXL documentation has a section related to working with [pandas](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html).

In your case, you'll need the [`openpyxl.utils.dataframe.dataframe_to_rows`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.dataframe.html#openpyxl.utils.dataframe.dataframe_to_rows) function.

From the documentation:

```py
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)
```

Comment: I dont know if you can see the edit but it wiped the whole sheet @ljmc

Comment: If your data is in the df dataframe and you do `wb.save("somepath.xlsx")`, then no way this wiped you data. It would not be part of the documentation if it wiped data.

Comment: Okay I am sorry probably should have mentioned this .. edited df is filtered and only contains certain columns, not not the whole df

Comment: How do you plan on writing these few filtered column to the existing table ? Or is this the question you have ?

Comment: I am trying edit ws using column name and header instead.. I will go with whatever you gave me and see if I can make it work

Comment: With the above, plus loading the original file as in [the tutorial](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=%22load_workbook%22#read-an-existing-workbook), I'm sure you can cook up exactly what you need. But feel free to comment again if you get stuck, I'll have another look.

Comment: The tutorial wasnt quite what I needed.. I pasted the code in the first post, hopefully ill find an anwser because I couldnt figure it out alone

Answer (score 0):

What I used was

```
# Will allow conversion to letters in later use
characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

# Look for IDC S/N column
counter = 0
for col in df.columns:
    if col == 'IDC S/N':
        print(col)
        print(counter)
        break
    else:
        counter += 1

# Find 'IDC S/N' within xlsx
if ws[f"{characters[counter]}1"].value == "IDC S/N":
    print('IDC S/N Exists.')
else:
    print('IDC S/N Missing, Will stop')
    quit()

# Converted numbers to letters - 1 = A , 2 = B
header = characters[counter]

# Search for memory within 'IDC S/N'
counter = 0
print(header)
for cell in ws[header]:
    print(cell)
```

From here I can edit cells because I have both header and index ..

If anyone has a more efficient alternative please do share!